# Moving element in canvas copies it multiple times until developer's console is opened

Tags: javascript, paperjs

what I am trying to achieve is loading a background image for a canvas and then create and move shapes around. Since I want to extend this functionality later, I am using paper.js (0.12.4) which comes with lots of examples and handy tools.

All in all I am able to do that, but I need to take an additional step by **opening** the browser console or **zoom in and out** (Firefox 74; Chrome 80.0.3987.149). Just then everything behaves as planned. Please see the GIF below.

[image]

Here is the code of the presentation above:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head >
        <title></title>

        <!-- Load Bootstrap and JQuery -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div>
                <canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">

            var hitOptions = {
                segments: true,
                stroke: true,
                fill: true,
                tolerance: 5
            };

            var segment, path;
            var movePath = false;
            function onMouseDown(event) {
                segment = path = null;
                var hitResult = project.hitTest(event.point, hitOptions);
                if (!hitResult)
                    return;

                if (event.modifiers.shift) {
                    if (hitResult.type == 'segment') {
                        hitResult.segment.remove();
                    };
                    return;
                }

                if (hitResult) {
                    path = hitResult.item;
                    if (hitResult.type == 'segment') {
                        segment = hitResult.segment;
                    } else if (hitResult.type == 'stroke') {
                        var location = hitResult.location;
                        segment = path.insert(location.index + 1, event.point);
                    }
                }
                movePath = hitResult.type == 'fill';
                if (movePath)
                    project.activeLayer.addChild(hitResult.item);
            }

            function onMouseDrag(event) {
                if (segment) {
                    segment.point += event.delta;
                } else if (path) {
                    path.position += event.delta;
                }
                logCanvasData();
            }

            function logCanvasData() {
                var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
                var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
                var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

                for (var i = 0; i < 120; i += 4) {
                    if (imgData.data[i] == 255) {
                        console.log("We have a color with red inside.");

                    } else if (imgData.data[i] == 0 && imgData.data[i+1] == 0 && imgData.data[i+2] == 0 && imgData.data[i+3] != 0){
                        console.log("We have a black value!");
                    }
                }
            }

            function onResize(event) {
                // Whenever the window is resized, recenter the path:
                path.position = view.center;
            }
        </script>

        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                // Loads the canvas element with a background image
                // and an example polygon.
                loadCanvas();
            }
        </script>
        <script>
            function loadCanvas(imageUrl, canvasId) {

                if (typeof imageUrl == "undefined") {
                    imageUrl = "teddy_bear.jpg";
                }

                if (typeof canvasId == "undefined") {
                    canvasId = "myCanvas";
                }

                canvasImageWidth = 0;
                canvasImageHeight = 0;
                var canvasImage = new Image();
                canvasImage.onload = function() {
                    // Determine the image size which will be the background of the canvas.
                    canvasImageWidth = this.width;
                    canvasImageHeight = this.height;

                    // Adjust the canvas size and set the background image.
                    var canvasElement = document.getElementById(canvasId);
                    canvasElement.width = canvasImageWidth;
                    canvasElement.height = canvasImageHeight;
                    canvasElement.style.background = "url(" + canvasImage.src + ")";

                    myPath = new paper.Path();
                    myPath.closed = true;

                    myPath.strokeColor = 'black';
                    myPath.fillColor = {hue:180, saturation:30, lightness:100}
                    myPath.add(new paper.Point(0, 0));
                    myPath.add(new paper.Point(100, 50));
                    myPath.add(new paper.Point(50, 150));
                    myPath.opacity = 0.3;

                };

                canvasImage.src = imageUrl;
            }
        </script>

        <!-- Load script to draw polygons -->
        <script src="paperjs-v0.12.4/dist/paper-full.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I believe that there is a solution to this problem. Any suggestions are appreciated.

---

## Possible solutions:

1. As shown in the fiddle by sasensi in a comment below his response: [sfiddle.net/xidi2xidi/v67odmjy](https://jsfiddle.net/xidi2xidi/v67odmjy/)
2. Another way that works but which depends a little bit on how you load the site and the image is the following. In my case image information are passed by a python Flask back-end, so that I can add them as style parameters of the canvas.

```html
<style>
  canvas[resize] {
    width: {{ imageWidth }}px;
    height: {{ imageHeight }}px;
    background-image: url("{{ imagePath }}");
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relying on Paper.js is a good idea as it will do a lot of the work for you.
In fact, you should also use it to draw your background and everything will be a lot simpler.

Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) demonstrating the solution.

```js
// Draw an image as background.
const raster = new Raster({
    source: 'http://assets.paperjs.org/images/marilyn.jpg',
    // Lower down the opacity so we can see the rest better.
    opacity: 0.4,
    // When image is loaded...
    onLoad: () => {
        // ...make sure that it fills the entire canvas.
        raster.fitBounds(view.bounds, true);
    }
});

// Draw a circle on top of the image.
const circle = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'orange',
    // On circle drag...
    onMouseDrag: event => {
        // ...move it.
        circle.position += event.delta;
    }
});

// Draw intsructions.
new PointText({
    content: 'Drag and drop the circle over the image',
    point: view.center + [0, -80],
    justification: 'center',
    fontSize: 24
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @sasensi. There is one problem that remains with the code that you have shared here: The canvas size would need to be set beforehand and would not be adjusted dynamically to the loaded image. I have not mentioned it explicitly, but the provided code includes the step of determining the canvas size based on the provided image URL .

Comment: In that case, I think that you should first load the image and set the canvas size accordingly before drawing on it. Here is a fiddle demonstrating a possible implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/xidi2xidi/v67odmjy/